# Assertion fails where it should pass: why?

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, debugging

In my Cocoa application, a property gets changed when it shouldn’t. In order to find out where it happens, I’ve put assertions which helped narrow down the problem (I did try “Watch variable” but couldn’t understand how it’s used). But now I am faced with an assertion that seems to do the opposite of what it’s supposed to (see screenshot).

I am using a custom operator (see below) to have the code run in another thread.

What am I missing, and what can I do to move forward?

[image: State of Xcode when the program crashes.]
*State of Xcode when the program crashes.*

[image: Stack trace.]
*Stack trace.*

```
import Foundation
infix operator ~>

/**
 Executes the lefthand closure on a background thread and,
 upon completion, the righthand closure on the main thread.
 Passes the background closure's output, if any, to the main closure.
 */
func ~> <R> (
    backgroundClosure: @escaping () -> R,
    mainClosure:       @escaping (_ result: R) -> ())
{
    queue.async {
        let result = backgroundClosure()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            mainClosure(result)
        }
    }
}

private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Edk4ServerRequests")
```

*Custom operator definition. (Code adapted from https://ijoshsmith.com/2014/07/05/custom-threading-operator-in-swift/)*

Comment: I added important information about the custom “~>” operator used in the sample.

Comment: I rewrote my code to make sure `isUpdating` wouldn’t get modified by another thread, and now it works. Still, I’d like to understand how, in the screenshot provided, the value of `isUpdating` is shown by the debugger to be `false` while the assertion failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a breakpoint on your attribute declaration. Execution will be stopped when the attribute value will be changed

[image]

Comment: That would be helpful. I just tried putting a breakpoint on “private var isUpdating: Bool” (not sure that is what you meant), ran again, but nothing changed.

Comment: that's it. When your `isUpdating` will be changed, the execution will be stopped

Comment: Well, it doesn’t stop. It does stop if I set a breakpoint on a global variable, though.